# how to pretty print the record of a list using ReactJS as JS object

Tags: reactjs

```
"data": { { "lon": -83.45, "lat": 39.89 }}
```

I want the output as

```
data : {

 "lon": -83.2,

 "lat": 39.89 

}
```

I tried using as `JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)` still am not getting any data no errors also

Comment: Explain a bit more what u want?

Comment: can u please check the question once i have update the format of the output

Answer (score 0):

Your json object is not proper it should be this

```
obj = {
"data": {
  "lon": -83.45,
  "lat": 39.89
}
};
```

instead of this

```
obj = {{
"data": {
  "lon": -83.45,
  "lat": 39.89
 }
}};
```

Here is an example you can try:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <pre id="ppp">
  </pre>
</body>
<script>
  obj = {
    "data": {
      "lon": -83.45,
      "lat": 39.89
    }
  };
  var str = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
  document.getElementById("ppp").innerHTML = str;
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your render method just do this,

```
render() {
   return (
     <div>
        <pre>{data}</pre>
     </div>
   );
}
```

Here I am assuming that `data` is the variable that holds the object that you want to output in a prettier way. I hope this helps.